# How to get int in string (Scanner)

Tags: java, scanf

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner ("2 text 3text");
scanner.nextInt(); // 2
scanner.next();    // text
scanner.nextInt(); // 3 ?
```

I want to get int(3). But int is not separated from string with space.

How to separate int from string?

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Yes. And number can be varable length. text is fixed length.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Yes, I am still working on.

Comment: So what it the problem? It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split by the characters that are not numbers in order to get numbers:

```
String[] split = s.split("\\D+"); // where s is your input string
```